# 551 error with Facebook Messenger bot - "This person isn't available right now"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I've written a simple bot for Facebook Messenger that takes a user's text, applies a simple transformation and immediately returns the result.

While testing it myself, I've never had a problem, but it seems that for some users, Facebook returns the following error when the transformed message is sent back (from my server logs):

"www-authenticate": "OAuth \"Facebook Platform\" \"invalid_request\" \"(#551) This person isn't available right now.\""

Any ideas what the cause of this would be? It seems to arbitrarily happen to random users, and users should be available as the result is returned immediately.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue with slightly different error:

"error": {
            "message": "(#200) This person isn't available right now.",
            "type": "OAuthException",
            "code": 200,
            "error_subcode": 1545041,
            "fbtrace_id": "BjhxVgB3eKj"
        }

Comment: Seems to be a confirmed bug on the Facebook side, having same issue btw, happens for every very first message from a new user: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/465154327166499/

Comment: @PavelShukhman I think this should be the answer. Also, since fb is idiotic/paranoid enough to put developer content behind a required login, it'd be nice if you could share details on this here so that it's public.

Comment: Ok, added as answer with details, thanks @m90

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is currently a confirmed bug on the Facebook platform. Bug location: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/465154327166499/ (as mentioned by @m90, Facebook developer account is required to view it).

**Bug description and steps to reproduce:**

1. Have a new Facebook user (who never interacted with your app before)
2. With that user, ask anything that normally produces automated response from the app

**Expected result:**
Bot should respond

**Actual result:**
For apps in development mode it is error code 551 as following:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#551) This person isn't available right now.","type":"OAuthException","code":551,"error_subcode":1545041, ...
```

For apps in production mode (already submitted and public) it is error 200 as following:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#200) This person isn't available right now.","type":"OAuthException","code":200,"error_subcode":1545041,...
```

Note: if the user sends more messages, bot starts to reply normally after the 2nd message from the same user.

Based on the information from the Facebook Platform bug page, the bug has appeared in the end of May 2017. On our side, we have been noticing this for the last week (since around June 5), important to note that new app submissions are also failing because of this issue.

**UPDATE June 09, 2017** Bug is marked as fixed and works on our side now. If you still experience issues, Facebook asks to comment on the bug page.

Comment: Thank you; this was exactly my problem as my app's being rejected in the submission process.

Comment: I am getting this error code right now. It was #200 but I am getting #551 and #10

Comment: @Tony you should probably post on the Facebook developer page. Not seeing this bug on our side currently.

Comment: @PavelShukhman I cannot find that page anymore and I also got barely any response when I posted there in the past.

Comment: The page is certainly active (please see the link in my original answer). You need to be registered as a developer on Facebook to be able to access it.

Comment: Now it appears to me again. could you give some solutions about it?

{"error":{"message":"(#551) 用户暂时收不到消息。","type":"OAuthException","code":551,"error_subcode":1545041,"fbtrace_id":"AjPXlxNssYq-OiBz1HYZuet"}}

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error, It was due to the fact that my page was unpublished. Once I published the Facebook Page this error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe FB user has set a barrier to your page.